# ubuntu 17.10 : how to install multiple desktop manager and switch between them

Tags: 17.10

ubuntu 17.10 use unity instead of gnome.
I do not have anymore in the log in screen the suggestion of which desktop manager to use.

how to switch desktop manager in ubuntu 17.10 ?

Comment: Did you try the tiny gear icon next to Sign in? That's it for me on 17.10